# user: Current not implemented on linux/amd64 with golang using docker scratch

Tags: go, docker

I have used [this](https://blog.codeship.com/building-minimal-docker-containers-for-go-applications/) tutorial to compile my go app to run on container derived from scratch.

My go code uses `user.Current()` from `os/user`. When I use the technique from the blog post I get the following error when running the container:

```
user: Current not implemented on linux/amd64
```

To elaborate more:

This is the command used to compile:

```
CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .
```

This is the Dockerfile used to create the image (`scratch` based):

```
FROM scratch
ADD ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
ADD main /
ENTRYPOINT ["/main"]
```

This is the command used to run the container:

```
sudo docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock --rm 813
```

Did anyone encounter this? Any solution?

Comment: user db access requires cgo on linux.

Comment: also, what do you want to do with `user.Current`? You can use `os.Getuid` if you don't need to lookup user information.

Comment: Thanks Jim. Will try with os.Getuid and report back.

Comment: You may also be able to get what you need simply using the `$USER` environment variable.

Answer (score 4):

The `os/user` package's user info lookup on Linux is implemented using the `getpwuid_r` system call, so will not work when compiled with `CGO_ENABLED=0`.

While implementing a `/etc/passwd` parser in Go sounds simple, the `getpwuid` function may retrieve the user information from a different source.  For instance, on some systems it might use an LDAP directory.  So the only way to get parity is to delegate to the C library.

Comment: Thank you James. My end goal is to create a small container for my golang app. AFAIU from your answer this can be achieved by statically linking with C library. Is this correct? If so, can you please share a pointer to how to do it?

Comment: @DimaStopel: statically linking glibc is not a good idea (you'll get warnings from the linker indicating this), as the runtime glibc still has to match the exact version.

Comment: Like @JimB, I wouldn't recommend statically linking with libc.  If you need it, just include it in your container.  With that said, if your app is the only thing in the container, what do you actually need `user.Current()` for?